# Recently added localized taxonomy terms not appearing in secondary language

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I'm running a multilingual site in two languages: English (default) and French.

I have a Vocabulary with the Translation Mode set to Localize. Everything was working fine until I added some new terms in English. I then used the translate interface to add French translations for these terms.

I have a term reference field that has the same value across all languages. When I set this value on the English node edit page, it works. When I switch over to the French node edit page, the value has defaulted to the first term in the list and the recently-added terms don't even appear.

I've tried refreshing the strings through the translate interface, flushing all caches, and running cron but nothing can get these new terms to appear in the French node edit form, and the values refuse to stick for any language except for English.

How can I refresh this Localized vocabulary so that the terms are the same for both languages?

I've made an album on imgur that hopefully gives a better idea of what's going on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoGhD.jpg

Comment: What exactly you consider a problem here? You added terms to one node, and wanted them to appear in another one, but they didn't? Or the fact new terms wasn't available on second language?

Comment: | the fact new terms wasn't available on second language

This is the problem. It's really bizarre too, because if I go to edit the field on the content type, all of the terms appear in French but not on the node edit form.

Comment: Are you sure you cleared your caches?

Comment: Yes, all of them. The new terms appear in the Manage Field interface for the Content Type, but not on the node edit form.

Comment: Try running cron, too. Nothing else comes to my mind now.

Comment: I just flushed all of the caches again and ran cron again. Still nothing.

Comment: I've added an imgur album that helps illustrate the problem.